# Which command can be used in Appium to switch between mobile app and web application?

Tags: appium, appium-android

Which command can be used in Appium to switch between mobile app and web application? 
For example I want to test a scenario where I need switch to the web app as well in between the mobile application testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean changing from Appium driver to Appium Web Driver (assuming chrome), you should change the driver context. (Examples in Python)

Run appium with any app as usual. Then:

For web pages/ web apps:

```
driver.switch_to.context('WEBVIEW_chrome')
```

and switch back tu pure appium:

```
driver.switch_to.context('NATIVE_APP')
```

Every time during run time you want to open any android apps/notifications, etc... You should change context to NATIVE_APP. 
Also anytime before opening chrome you should change context to WEBVIEW then run `driver.get("https://sample.com")` - can be any web pages or web apps.

Please be note that:

1- In webdriver context you should locate the elements with selenium locating strategy. Like `"html/body/div/div/span[2]"` (abs-xpath) or `#div.class>span` (css)

2- This will not running selenium WebDriver. Selenium webdriver is for desktops only. In case of mobile you should only use Appium and using driver context.

Hope this helps.